# Getting 400 BAD Request when using Spring RestTemplate to POST

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, box-api

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with the code below?

I am using **Spring 3.1.1 RestTemplate** to try to call a **REST WS on Box.com** to get a new access token from a refresh token.

The code below is returning a `400 (BAD REQUEST)`. I am able to *successfully* call the same method using the **FireFox POST plugin**. I've compared output from the `writeForm method` on the `FormHttpMessageConverter class` and it is exactly as I am sending it from FireFox.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        String apiUrl = "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token";
        String clientSecret = "[MY SECRET]";
        String clientId = "[MY ID]";
        String currentRefreshToken = "[MY CURRENT VALID REFRESHTOKEN]";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();

        messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

        body.add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
        body.add("refresh_token", currentRefreshToken);
        body.add("client_id", clientId);
        body.add("client_secret", clientSecret);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,application/json");
        headers.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");


        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);

        restTemplate.exchange(apiUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("ex = " + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the response for an error code.

Comment: Spring is throwing an **exception** (`HttpClientErrorException`) that only shows `statusCode` of `400` and `detailMessage` of `400 Bad Request`

Comment: Check the body. HttpClientErrorException.getResponseBodyAsString()

Comment: Did you get a solution for your problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: HttpClientErrorException.getResponseBodyAsString() will give the error resonse, Usinf that u can  identify  the issue. most probably it would be the incorrect headers

Answer (score 3):

The no-arg constructor for [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) uses the `java.net` API to make requests, which does not support gzip encoding. There is, however, a constructor that accepts a [`ClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html). You can use the [`HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html) implementation, which uses the Apache HttpComponents HttpClient API to make requests. This *does* support gzip encoding. So you can do something like the following (from the [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate)) when creating your `RestTemplate`:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot, adding something like this to `pom.xml` seems to add some magic.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
    <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm assume that there are other, similar, solutions...

Answer (score 0):

double check the HttpHeaders properly !!